# While searching using EditText, the items in Recyclerview is duplicating, if i am searching fast

Tags: android, android-edittext, duplicates, android-recyclerview

In my project, there is need of searching data from server using keyword. After search, i am displaying results using RecyclerView . While searching fast, the data in RecyclerView is duplicating. If searching slowly, it's working fine. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

The below code for making server call:

```
 private void callSearchUserApi(final String searchText, int currentPage, boolean clearData) {

    isApiCallInProcess = true;

    String URL = "userinfo/api/v1/user-search/" + "?page=" + currentPage;

    if (!Connectivity.isConnected(activity)) {
        Common.snackBarNoConnection(activity, activity.getString(R.string.no_conection));
        //setOnProgressbarVisibility(View.GONE);
        return;
    }

    if (clearData) {
        globalSearchUsersModelList.clear();
        //BS globalSearchUserResultsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    ApiInterface apiCall = ApiClient.getApiService(activity);
    final Call<SearchUsersModel> globalUserSearchApiCall = apiCall.searchUser(
            URL,
            searchText);
    globalUserSearchApiCall.enqueue(new Callback<SearchUsersModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SearchUsersModel> call, Response<SearchUsersModel> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body().getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(Common.SUCCESS_RESPONSE)) {

                //BS globalSearchUsersModelList.addAll(response.body().getData().getData());

                for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getData().getData().size(); i++) {

                    SearchUsersModel.DataBeanX.DataBean dataBean = new SearchUsersModel.DataBeanX.DataBean();
                    dataBean.setDesignation(response.body().getData().getData().get(i).getDesignation());
                    dataBean.setFull_name(response.body().getData().getData().get(i).getFull_name());
                    dataBean.setGender(response.body().getData().getData().get(i).getGender());
                    dataBean.setId(response.body().getData().getData().get(i).getId());
                    dataBean.setPlace(response.body().getData().getData().get(i).getPlace());
                    dataBean.setProfile_pic(response.body().getData().getData().get(i).getProfile_pic());

                    globalSearchUsersModelList.add(dataBean);


                    /*BS if (!globalSearchUsersModelList.contains(response.body().getData().getData().get(i)))
                        globalSearchUsersModelList.add(response.body().getData().getData().get(i));*/
                }

                CURRENT_PAGE = response.body().getData().getPage();

                isLoading = false;
                if (response.body().getData().isNext() == false)
                    isLastPage = true;
                else
                    isLastPage = false;


                if (globalSearchUsersModelList.size() == 0) {
                    rv_GlobalsearchList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    rl_placeholderGSPeople.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv_placeholderGSPeople.setText(activity.getString(R.string.no_search_found) + " " + searchText);

                } else {
                    rv_GlobalsearchList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    rl_placeholderGSPeople.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }

                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        globalSearchUserResultsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });



            }

            if (searchTextsList.size() > 0) {
                String sText = searchTextsList.get(0);
                searchTextsList.remove(0);
                callSearchUserApi(sText, FIRST_PAGE, true);

            } else
                isApiCallInProcess = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SearchUsersModel> call, Throwable t) {
            isApiCallInProcess = false;
        }
    });
}
```

This is my Adapter.

```
public class GlobalSearchUserResultsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GlobalSearchUserResultsAdapter.SearchViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<SearchUsersModel.DataBeanX.DataBean> searchUserList;

public GlobalSearchUserResultsAdapter(Context context, List<SearchUsersModel.DataBeanX.DataBean> searchUserList){
    this.context = context;
    this.searchUserList = searchUserList;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    Log.v("Search", "Adapter Activity : "+context);

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.global_search_row, parent, false);
    return new GlobalSearchUserResultsAdapter.SearchViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(GlobalSearchUserResultsAdapter.SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if ( searchUserList.get(position).getGender().equals("M")) {
        holder.iv_userImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_border_with_circle_appblue);
        Common.setGlideImage((GlobalSearchActivity)context,
                holder.iv_userImage,
                /*searchUsersModel*/searchUserList.get(position).getProfile_pic(),
                R.drawable.male,
                true);


    } else if (searchUserList.get(position).getGender().equals("F")) {
        holder.iv_userImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_border_with_circle_pink);
        Common.setGlideImage((GlobalSearchActivity)context,
                holder.iv_userImage,
                searchUserList.get(position).getProfile_pic(),
                R.drawable.female,
                true);
    } else {
        Common.setGlideImage((GlobalSearchActivity)context,
                holder.iv_userImage,
                searchUserList.get(position).getProfile_pic(),
                R.drawable.deafult_profilepic,
                true);
    }

    holder.tv_userName.setText(searchUserList.get(position).getFull_name());
    holder.tv_userName.setTypeface(Common
            .getFontTypeface(context, GlobalConstants.FONT_AVENIR_MEDIUM));
    holder.tv_place.setText(searchUserList.get(position).getPlace());
    holder.tv_place.setTypeface(Common
            .getFontTypeface(context, GlobalConstants.FONT_AVENIR_MEDIUM));
    holder.designation.setText(searchUserList.get(position).getDesignation());
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return searchUserList.size();
}

public class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private ImageView iv_userImage;
    private TextView tv_userName;
    private TextView tv_place;
    private TextView designation;

    public SearchViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.iv_userImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageSearch);
        this.tv_userName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameSearch);
        tv_userName.setTypeface(Common.getFontTypeface(context,
                GlobalConstants.FONT_AVENIR_MEDIUM));
        this.designation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.designation);
        designation.setTypeface(Common.getFontTypeface(context,
                GlobalConstants.FONT_AVENIR_MEDIUM));
        this.tv_place = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.placeSearch);
        tv_place.setTypeface(Common.getFontTypeface(context,
                GlobalConstants.FONT_AVENIR_LIGHT));

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ProfileActivity.class)//ThirdParty
                        .putExtra(GlobalConstants.KEY_THIRD_PARTY_ID, searchUserList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId()));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

}

Comment: There is no enough information to help you, please take a look into https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are u sure the ArrayList clear before calling the services

Comment: Would be better if you add more information.

Comment: Yes. i am clearing the ArrayList before loading new data.

Comment: @balu.raslras if you are looking for solution, you have to provide the code, so that we can find out if anything you are missing.

Comment: hi @KrishnaSharma , i added the code. pls check.

Comment: You just had to clear the **globalSearchUsersModelList** list just before for loop, because api call is asynchronous call.

Comment: Before making reftrofit call, i am clearing globalSearchUsersModelList every time.

Comment: Can you try once please, what I mentioned

Comment: suggestion, would be better if you assign this response.body().getData().getData()  into a vairable instead calling each time.

Comment: hi bro, @KrishnaSharma, you are awesome. as you said, i am clearing array just before adding new data. working awesome. Thank you much with lots of love.

Comment: Sure i will assign response.body().getData().getData().size(); to a variable. Thank you much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just had to clear the `globalSearchUsersModelList` list just before for loop, because API call is asynchronous.

```
globalSearchUsersModelList.clear();// Important one
for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getData().getData().size(); i++) {
// do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Working like a charm. I don't have enough reputation to up vote. But, +100 Thank you much.

Comment: @balu.raslras Awesome !! Glad to know I could solve your problem. Your words meant a lot to me, Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue come from your getItemId implementation. The way you implement it, the recycler view will identify an item according to its position in the list.

If you change this and use unique identification for instance `searchUserList.get(position).id` (if your User object has an unique ID) the problem should be fixed

You can also add in your activity `adapter.setHasStableIds(true)`